# PHP Steam API HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php

Example : http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=FR&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Fracture Case

This work if i write it in chrome.

```
    $url= html_entity_decode('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=FR&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name='.$pts['market_hash_name']);
    $itemPrice = file_get_contents($url);
    $itemPriceResponse = json_decode($itemPrice,true);
```

This return [*Error*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ0rM.png)

The problem is the &amp because :

- input : FR&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name
- output: FR&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name

Already try str_replace()

Thanks for help

Comment: You're decoding instead of encoding, so that space isn't becoming `%20`. And you should only modify the market_hash_name or else any command you may use would convert everything in the URL

Comment: Can you tell me how to encode so ? ( Im new with this ) ^^